# How can I control .NET Fez Panda II from a WPF application?

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

I have a problem with my application. I prepared a library in [.NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) to control lights (I only want to turn on or off lights). I can test my library with a console application, but when I added a new WPF application to control lights via a button, I could not add a library to references. Example: `Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware` can not be imported to references.

I use .NET [FEZ Panda II](http://wiki.tinyclr.com/index.php?title=FEZ_Panda_II) and GHI NETMF v4.1 SDK.

Note: I only want to turn off and on via a button. Do I need to use a Bluetooth or wireless sensor to communicate with Fez?

Comment: "Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware can not import to references." can you give us more information on this error - what you're trying, exactly what it's telling you?

Comment: hi @Rup, I can not find Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware in references list. and i want to learn how to send an input message to Fez from a wpf app. i connect fez to my computer with usb port.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware is part of the .NET Micro Framework. If you cant find it in the list under the .NET Tab when adding a reference, you may either; 1:) Not have the Microsoft .NET Micro Framework installed; or 2:) Youre not selecting the correct Application type when youre creating your project.

I would follow the instructions here to make sure you have all the correct SDK's Installed.: [tinyCLR Support Website](http://www.tinyclr.com/support)

Also, important is this link: [Adding Refferences to a FEZ Project](http://wiki.tinyclr.com/index.php?title=First_Project)

Make sure the firmware is uptodate on your Panda also as instructed by the Guys at GHI Electronics. This has nothing to do with the reference, but is always good practice.

Then start with the Tutorial Section at the above address. The site is excellent for what youre trying to do. It even has a project for blinking LED's like youre doing.

This below Code is for Fading an LED, its from the tinyCLR Website:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.SPOT;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;

using GHIElectronics.NETMF.Hardware;
using GHIElectronics.NETMF.FEZ;

public class Program
{

static PWM MyFader = new PWM((PWM.Pin)FEZ_Pin.PWM.Di5);

public static void Main()
{
byte i = 0;
while (true)
{
MyFader.Set(10000, i);
if (i++ >= 100)
{
i = 0;
}
Thread.Sleep(10);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Also check out the GHI YouTube Videos @ http://www.youtube.com/user/GHIElectronics/videos and particularly this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiApuV-YyTw&feature=plcp